# Developer story tab - redirect to tag

Tags: discussion, feature-request, developer-story

In **[Developer story tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/10961238)** we can see the contribution of user for particular technology or tag. It will be nice if clicking on those tags redirect to some meaningful page/tab. There can be a two options

- Redirect to tag page
- Redirect to answers for tag given by a user